# Why is the width of the table row (tr) of a table element not working, but the height is?

Tags: html, css

Here's my code:

```css
.table1 {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: ;
  align-items: ;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-left: ;
}

.table1 tr {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1">

  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Why is it that i can change the height of the "TR" but i can't change the width?

And yes, i know i can change the width using padding on the parent block, but why is it not working by just changing the width of the TR elements itself like it does for the height?

Comment: why do you need to reset display to flex for the table ? What's the idea?

Comment: That's because the minimum content width of the `<table>` is already too large. Also, why would you ever want to use `display: flex` on a table element? It defeats the purpose of using it (not to mention introducing unexpected behavior).

Comment: Also, you do not seem to be aware that browser create the tbody tag when missing in the code ? try `tbody{display:none}` (oups gone!)  or `tbody{display:flex}`if flex is what you wanted

Comment: The width of `tr` elements are always 100% of the width of the `table` element. You can't have a wide row, then a skinny row. You can, however, have a tall row, then a short row. That's just how tables work.

Comment: I have used display flex to separate the table block from its content in order to change the properties of both separately. If you run the code you would see i have changed the background of both elements separately, something you can't do if you don't separate the two elements. I am just experimenting.

Comment: Heretic Monkey - but right now, the width of the tr is not the same as width of the table. I sit because of the display flex which separates the two elements? If i remove the flex, the tr adjusts to the table and i can't change the height of the TR separately anymore. So isn't it strange that you can separate the two elements and make the table into a block, and separately work on the TR by changing height and other properties, but not width, but you can change the width of the table irrespective of the width of the TR?

Answer (score 0):

Try set `flex` on `tbody` with `flex-direction: column` as follows:

```css
.table1 tbody {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: ;
  align-items: ;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-left: ;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.table1 tr {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
.table1 tr td, .table1 tr th {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1">

  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Please note that I've just added `width` to `td` and `th` as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question of why the `tr` element does not respect the setting of the `width` property. It just removes the `width` property.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else mentioned, a `tr` is always 100% the width of the table itself, but the height attribute is adjustable. This is why the height attribute in your code works but the width attribute does not.

To adjust the width attributes of your columns all you have to do is target the `th` element. For example, if you add the following code to your CSS sheet then you'll see your widths change.

```
th {
  width:50px;
}
```

Or, for more specificity, you can do the following.

```
.table1 tr th {
  width:50px;
}
```

You can also have different widths for each column. For example, your *First Name* column can be 100px while your *Last Name* column could be 150px.
It may go  without saying, but the total combined width of all of your columns should not exceed the width of the table itself.

Comment: I tried targeting th but only the right side of the width changes, the left is still stuck to the border and doesn't move. Also, like i said above, isn't it strange that the width doesn't change given that i have used display flex to separate the two elements? The width of the table element moves freely, but the inside element not. Isn't that strange?

Comment: The left side sticks to the border because that's the start of the table element. Are you saying that you want space between the blue table and the grey border/box? To do that you can just add padding to your .table1 selector.
And I am not certain what you mean by "The width of the table element moves freely, but the inside element not. Isn't that strange?". The only content is the table. There is nothing else in that code which would impact the flex display.

Comment: Well, there's the element and then there's the content inside the element. If the element is a block element, you can create space between the element and the inside content. If its an inline-block, you have to make it a block first to be able to do that. I can and i have created a background color between the element table and the inside elements. Anyway, yes i know i can change the width with padding, but why is it not working with just width is what i was wondering.